# Get Value of Input as Parameter For Constructor - Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, input

I'm building the Javascript code below, primarily for practice. I'm a novice at JS and don't have any experience of building large scale projects so I'm using this as a way to get past the beginner stage and write code that is more useful/fun.

I would like to know, how do I get the value from the input field in my viewTemplate() class then pass it into the name parameter of my Hero() class? Please see code:

```
function Hero(name) {
    this.name = name;

    // all the methods normally live here ....

}

function viewTemplate() {
    this.template = document.querySelector('.stage');

    this.textInput = function(id, label) {
        this.label = document.createElement('label');
        this.label.setAttribute("for", id);
        this.label.innerHTML = label;
        this.input = document.createElement('input');
        this.input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        this.input.setAttribute('value', '');
        this.input.setAttribute('id', id);
        this.template.appendChild(this.label);
        this.template.appendChild(this.input);
    }   

}


// Test cases
// Create a new template
var template = new viewTemplate();
template.textInput("form1", "Enter your name, oh heroic one!");

// Create a hero
var hero = new Hero("Ryan");
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ray_silver/2jd6e7cr/

Am I going about this the right way? I want to get the value from the input field and when I hit enter, it should take the value of the input as the name of the hero.

Comment: Is this what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/Gigapedia/2jd6e7cr/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listeners implemented in Javascript. For example, this piece of code could be added to the end of your script.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]; 
inputs.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){    // keypress event
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;  // determining which was pressed
    if (key === 13){                 // checking if the key pressed is Enter (keyCode 13 is Enter)
        hero.name = inputs.value;    // assigning input value to the object
        console.log(hero.name);      // testing
    }
});
```